# Submitted date of apex jobs = 15.12.2017 and how long it took to run?

Tags: apex, job

our client notified us that a scheduled job ran on the 15th December 2017 and it took longer than expected. Checking the processed jobs and their submitted dates, I couldn't find any job running on the 15th December, although the job has been scheduled for running daily. It shows that it ran from 28th December.

How can I check, for example via a SOQL query, if the APEX job really ran on the 15th December and how long it took to run?.

I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check details I would go to Salesforce Job Monitoring UI because the code doesn't have access to much details.

If you still want to go with a code you can check next execution time, previous execution time querying CronTrigger:

```
CronJobDetail jobDetail = [SELECT Id, Name, JobType FROM CronJobDetail WHERE Id = :'JobDetailId'];
```

You can find useful information at:

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_monitoring
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm